# CGI Script For Python Webserver

Tags: python, bash, nginx, webserver, cgi

I have a simple python webserver but I want to use the CGI script  for file download and upload  according to  client-request .But I couldnt find the any way of adjusting the CGI except using apache2 ,nginx or etc...  Is there any way to adjust cgi script to my python webserver  with Bash script or with other way ? Can you give me any advice about it?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not try to pass the address/location of your file which you want to download as a argument to the class and then use that in the < a href> tag to convert that into the link and implement the download functionality

Comment: it 's good idea but I want  to use multithreading   for cgi script for quick response , yes I know there is FastGGI  but  it will be good practice for me İf I can . I m actually try to make some cloud system or any webside by myself with which have a basic and practical requirements.

Answer (score 0):

U can specify cgi-scripts via [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and use it for data-transfer. Is that what u looking for ?

```
echo -e "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
```

Or do u want create an [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) ? There are some on the free market already, called myCloud.

Maybe u could give us some more intel.

Comment: The idea is  similar with NAS but I just want to use some specific folder to upload or download the data  with python or bash script or combination of both  . for example  I can share the text.txt filefrom my   /home/xxxx  folder

Comment: this are two pair of shoes. for example, with bash u can read files and move them locally, u cant use any kind of network nor service, unless u install some service and communicate via them. a web-server can create a connection to a script so it can process some data and send some data back,  an web server can also access files so there is no need to deliver files via third persons. Maybe u havent know this, but  If u still need to do this then you need some servlce like samba, ssh. ssl, nfs, rsync ....